# How to get the vurtuemart shippment method tax rate?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5.4 and Virtuemart 2.0.6. I want to display the shipment method TAX rate(calc_value) in the Virtuemart cart. How to get the shipment method tax rate in the virtuemart cart ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
    $cart->prices['shipmentTax'];
```

This may help..

Comment: I think this is shipmentTax amount, I want to display the shipment tax rate(calc_value),That is like this(15%).